# Why "abc" in String x = "abc".toUpperCase() is not included in an intern pool?

Tags: java

Whenever I do a string conversion (like to uppercase - using toUpperCase()), does a new string object always get created (not using interning)?
Also, I tried to test something myself with the code below:

```
String x = "abc".toUpperCase();
String y = "abc";
String z = "ABC";
System.out.println(x == y); // returns false
System.out.println(x == z); // returns false
```

I thought "abc" would put an object into an intern pool while toUpperCase() seems to be just using new keyword without String.intern().
However, it did not go as I expected.
x == y gave me a false value. Why "abc" is not pushed into an intern pool?
I thought calling a string using a literal format -e.g. "abc" - would do like new String("abc").intern() automatically?

Comment: `x` is set to `"ABC"`, `y` is set to `"abc"`. String interning aside, why should `x == y` *ever* return true?

Comment: Sorry, but your question makes little sense.  Why would you expect two strings that clearly have different characters to be `==` ?

Comment: `String`s are **immutible**; once created, they **never change**.  So anytime you're doing something that _looks_ like it's changing a `String` (like `"abc".toUpperCase()`), it's actually making an entirely new `String` and leaving the original unaltered.

Comment: @KevinAnderson I think the question is why such operation creates entirely new instance and don't just take one from string pool or put it in there for future use.

Comment: Let's clarify things a little further then: **no new `String` is ever interned**, unless you intern it explicitly by calling `intern()` on it.

Comment: @KevinAnderson if you mean `new String("abc")` then thats true. If you mean a string literal, the it will be interned. Not sure why would anyone want to use the former tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify, I assume here that the main point of your question was comparing `x == z` - two uppercase strings - and not `x == y` which would always be false because one is uppercase and the other is lowercase and this has nothing to do with interning.

[JVMS 8 5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.1) says:

> A string literal is a reference to an instance of class String, and is
> derived from a CONSTANT_String_info structure (§4.4.3) in the binary
> representation of a class or interface. The CONSTANT_String_info
> structure gives the sequence of Unicode code points constituting the
> string literal.
>
> The Java programming language requires that identical string literals
> (that is, literals that contain the same sequence of code points) must
> refer to the same instance of class String (JLS §3.10.5). In addition,
> if the method String.intern is called on any string, the result is a
> reference to the same class instance that would be returned if that
> string appeared as a literal. Thus, the following expression must have
> the value true:
>
> ```
> ("a" + "b" + "c").intern() == "abc"
> ```
>
> To derive a string literal, the Java Virtual Machine examines the
> sequence of code points given by the CONSTANT_String_info structure.
>
> If the method String.intern has previously been called on an instance of class String containing a sequence of Unicode code points
> identical to that given by the CONSTANT_String_info structure, then
> the result of string literal derivation is a reference to that same
> instance of class String.
>
> Otherwise, a new instance of class String is created containing the sequence of Unicode code points given by the CONSTANT_String_info
> structure; a reference to that class instance is the result of string
> literal derivation. Finally, the intern method of the new String
> instance is invoked.

The important parts here is that only string literals are put in a so called string pool and ones on which `.intern()` is explicitly called. Same goes to "taking" instances from the string pool. So if a string is created in any other way than specified as a string literal or is recieved from `intern()` method, it won't be an instance from string pool nor it will be added there.

A following example shows a little bit better how it works:

```
String a = "abc".toUpperCase().intern();
String b = "abc".toUpperCase();
String c = "ABC";
String d = "ABC";

System.out.println(a == b); // returns false
System.out.println(a == c); // returns true
System.out.println(b == c); // returns false
System.out.println(c == d); // returns true
```

Comment: Thank you. 
I understand that in cases of either calling a intern() or string literal, java uses 
an intern pool. Other than that, it won't be referencing an intern pool.
So, "abc".toUpperCase() function actually does not call from intern pool since it is calling toUpperCase().
I mean it is not just an literal like "abc".
So, that is why a == b is not equal

Comment: Continue from the above:
That was why x="abc".toUppercase() - which is not using an intern pool which means that it is not saving a reference inside an intern pool -
and z = "ABC" are not the same. However z is saving its reference to an intern pool for the first time for "ABC" 
So, Afterwards like comparing it would be the same.
e.g. 
c = "ABC" 
z==c -> it should come out as true.

Comment: Continue from the above: 

I have one more quick question. Could you answer this one as well? 

I understand that "ABC" object is not put into an intern pool for sure, but how about "abc"?
does "abc" from  "abc".toUpperCase() get to put into an intern pool as well? 
Or, it is not, so it is not a subject for gc? 
Thank you!

Comment: Actually, I don't really know. I'd assume that no because there is never a reference to "abc" anyway.